# I have this error in MySQL but I don't know why

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have this error at line 3 (sup_id) however I don't know why.
It should be correct.

I am using this SQL; I tried changing the name and the type everything nothing worked. This part of my work is for a college project.

```
create table supplier
(
sup_id number (12),
 contact number (12),
 Name varchar2 (30) NOT NULL, 
 constraint id_pk primary key (sup_id));
```

At line 3 it says error.

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using? SQL Server and MySQL are two different products/

Comment: varchar2 is not available in sql server. try varchar if it is sql server

Comment: Number is not a sql server datatype allowed, change it by int, float, decimal or whatever you expect of those attributes. It would be clearer for your future questions providing the error returned. It doesn’t require too much effort from your side and it makes the question easier to solve.

Comment: (In addition, it would be good too if you read the error message, in this particular case should be quite clear about what’s wrong)

Comment: Thank you it worked because as you all mentioned because of the naming int and varchar Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

It may happen due to incorrect naming. As [mentioned in the comments by @saravanatn:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55434226/i-have-this-error-but-i-dont-even-know-why-please-help-me/55434286#comment97585921_55434226)

> varchar2 is not available in sql server. try varchar if it is sql server

Try to use varchar instead of varchar2.

Comment: Why do you answer the same that somebody answered before?

Comment: @JaimeDrq: if someone wishes to add the answer in a comment, then someone else is at liberty to copy it into an answer, as long as it is appropriately credited. The licensing conditions permit this here.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @halfer, but I still don’t know well the motivation of doing this.

Comment: @JaimeDrq: I am not sure what further clarification you are seeking. Answers belong in the answer box `:-)`.

Comment: Thank you it worked because as you all mentioned because of the naming int and varchar Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is Oracle code.  The equivalent in MySQL is:

```
create table supplier (
  sup_id int,
  contact int,
  Name varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
  constraint id_pk primary key (sup_id)
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c940d23674827a04b6462623029327d1) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you it worked because as you all mentioned because of the naming int and varchar Thanks a lot again!